# MySQL command line run script twice

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a script with MySQL on Windows like this :

```
mysql.exe -h 127.0.0.1  databaseName -uroot < path\to\my\script.sql
```

On my script I do some stuff like this

```
select 'start'; 

select 'import';
SOURCE import some other sql with functions and procedures

select 'run';
some stuff

select 'end';
```

And when I'm looking for logs I found this :

```
start
start
import
import
run
run
end
end
```

Did you know why MySQL is doing this ?

Comment: what logs do you check? what command do you use to output to log? provide script.sql

Comment: when I say logs, I'm means all select statement on the script I can see on the standard output

Comment: so if your script contain just 1 line `select 'start';` are you still getting it twice? seem like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/98044 mysql is outputting **column title** and **values**. so to check this theory you can try `select 'start' as my_command;` You'll see the difference ;-)

Comment: yep that is my problem

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/98046

Comment: oh god ...., values are displayed twice : one for the column name, the other for the value. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/98044

mysql is outputting column title and values.

To check this theory you can try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/98046

```
select 'start' as my_command;
```

or

```
select 'start' as step;
```

You'll see the difference ;-)